# Higher Dimension Matrix Transpose

Tags: math, matrix

I am building a matrix library, and for the platform I am writing it for, there are fast matrix transpose functions I can call but they only work for 2D matrices.

So if I have a 5 dimensional matrix, is there any way to break down the transposition into a series of 2D operations that can then be parallelized?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you must mean to swap the elements around. Another way to accomplish the effect of a matrix transposition is to swap strides and offsets to use in computing 1-dimensional indices from 2-dimensional. In more than 2 dimensions, I guess it is probably permuting the strides and offsets. This assumes all the elements are stored in a single 1-dimensional list.

Comment: Are you really sure that you mean 2D matrices? A square 2D matrix consists of four entries (that's one of the most common interpretations of 2D) and transposing it means swapping the two off-diagonal entries. I doubt that there is a special library function for that. Do maybe mean a higher-order tensor?